# How can I update QListView widget after adding an element?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview

I have a QListView and I add elements using "for" cycle. It seems to take long time so I want elements immediately appear after I add them.

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.listview = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.listview.setModel(self.model)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.listview)
        self.refreshbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Refresh")
        self.refreshbtn.clicked.connect(self.get_messages)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.refreshbtn)
    def get_messages(self):
        for i in some_list:
             self.model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(some_list[i]))
             # I want to refresh my ListView widget here
```

How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: sorry, what is `some_list` and how many elements are in it.

Comment: @S.Nick, it doen't matter. Actually, I already solved the problem using QEventLoop